# Find all positive integers $x$ such that $[\frac{x}{5}]-[\frac{x}{7}]=1$, where, for any real number $t$, $[t]$ denotes the greatest integer $\le t$

Tags: functions, inequality

I have tried the following steps:

$[\dfrac{x}{5}]-[\dfrac{x}{7}]=1$

@Berci suggested this:

$[\dfrac{x}{5}]\le\dfrac{x}{5}$

$-[\dfrac{x}{7}]<-\dfrac{x}{7}+1$

$\implies [\dfrac{x}{5}]-[\dfrac{x}{7}]<\dfrac{x}{5}-\dfrac{x}{7}+1 $

$\implies x>0$

$\implies x> 0$

$\implies x \in [1,.... \infty]$

Next is a manual observation, we will see that numbers lets say $n\equiv1(mod 5)\implies n\equiv 5k+1 $ where $k\in \{1,2,3,4\}$

why $k\in \{1,2,3,4\}$? why not $k\in \mathbb{N}$?

Lets see:

Hence if we try numbers like $6,11,16,21$ we will see that 
$[\dfrac{x}{5}]-[\dfrac{x}{7}]=1$

But the moment one tries with $x=26,36$ we will see $[\dfrac{x}{5}]-[\dfrac{x}{7}]=2$

Again with $x=41,46,51,56$ we see $[\dfrac{x}{5}]-[\dfrac{x}{7}]=2$

And so on as will proceed and this $[\dfrac{x}{5}]-[\dfrac{x}{7}]>1$ and increases more and more.

Again if we try $x=12,13$,we get $[\dfrac{x}{5}]-[\dfrac{x}{7}]=1$

Also $x=5$ is a solution.

So is it the answer that $x \in {5,6,11,12,13,16,21}$?

Comment: `I doubt that this is wrong` Try $\,x=7\,$ or $\,x=20\,$ for example.

Comment: How do you use $[\dfrac{x}{5}]\le\dfrac{x}{5}\le [\dfrac{x}{5}]+1 $
and $[\dfrac{x}{7}]\le\dfrac{x}{7}\le [\dfrac{x}{7}]+1 $ to deduce
$[\dfrac{x}{5}]-[\dfrac{x}{7}]\le\dfrac{x}{5}-\dfrac{x}{7}$? Please be specific.

Comment: No, @Berci did not suggest that... $\implies x>\frac{35}2$.

Comment: @Did I have corrected my errors as suggested by Berci. My point has been cleared.

Comment: @Did please edit the error if you can. I tried to add up the two equations to get that.

Comment: "I have corrected my errors as suggested by Berci" But you added other incorrect steps, such as the one I mentioned. Please correct them.

Comment: "$\implies x>0$" Right, which gives you nothing. Any other idea?

Comment: @Did Yes thats right if I put x=7 or x=20, we won't get $[x/5]-[x/7]=1$ if $x\in[1,...\infty]$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76489/discussion-between-saradamani-and-did).

Comment: $x=5$ or $x=13$ are also solutions

Comment: @Legoman $x=13$ already there. Included $x=5$ just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a meaningful bound, you need the inequalities in the other way: $\left[\dfrac{x}{5}\right]\ge \dfrac{x}{5}-1$ and $\left[\dfrac{x}{7}\right]\le \dfrac{x}{7}$. Hence, $$\left[\dfrac{x}{5}\right]-\left[\dfrac{x}{7}\right]\ge \frac{x}{5}-1-\frac{x}7=\frac{2x}{35}-1$$ Now, for any $x\ge 36$, you have that $$x\ge 36\implies \frac{2x}{35}-1\ge \frac{2\cdot36}{35}-1>1$$ which implies that $$\left[\dfrac{x}{5}\right]-\left[\dfrac{x}{7}\right]>1$$ for any $x\ge 36$. So, your candidate solutions are the integers $1,\dots, 35$. Trial and error will work. A direct substitution shows that $35$ does not work. So, to do it more efficiently, observe that for $x\in \{1,\dots,34\}$, $\left[\dfrac{x}{5}\right]$ takes only $7$ values and $\left[\dfrac{x}{7}\right]$ only $5$.
A systematic way to do it is the following:

- For $x=1,\dots,6$: $\left[\dfrac{x}{7}\right]=0$. Hence, $x=5,6$ will do, since for these values $\left[\dfrac{x}{5}\right]=1$.
- For $x=7,\dots,13$: $\left[\dfrac{x}{7}\right]=1$. Hence, $x=10,\dots,13$ will do, since for these values $\left[\dfrac{x}{5}\right]=2$.
- For $x=14,\dots,20$: $\left[\dfrac{x}{7}\right]=2$. Hence, $x=15,\dots,19$ will do, since for these values $\left[\dfrac{x}{5}\right]=3$.
- For $x=21,\dots,27$: $\left[\dfrac{x}{7}\right]=3$. Hence, $x=21,\dots,24$ will do, since for these values $\left[\dfrac{x}{5}\right]=4$.
- For $x=28,\dots,34$: $\left[\dfrac{x}{7}\right]=4$. Hence, $x=28,29$ will do, since for these values $\left[\dfrac{x}{5}\right]=5$.

This gives you the complete set of solutions, which is $$\{5,6,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,28,29\}$$